# How to style react-native-sectioned-multi-select?

Tags: reactjs, select, native

I'm using react-native-sectioned-multi-select in react native. But, I couldn't do any style to that. Can anyone help me to customize and do styling for this one?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sectioned-multi-select?activeTab=readme

https://reactnativeexample.com/simple-multi-select-component-for-react-native/

Comment: Create a css file override the css using `!importent` and import that css file in index.js.

Answer (score 5):

```
 styles={{
            // chipText: {
            //   maxWidth: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 90,
            // },
            // itemText: {
            //   color: this.state.selectedItems.length ? 'black' : 'lightgrey'
            // },
            selectedItemText: {
              color: 'blue',
            },
            // subItemText: {
            //   color: this.state.selectedItems.length ? 'black' : 'lightgrey'
            // },
            selectedSubItemText: {
              color: 'blue',
            },
          }}
```

> [https://github.com/renrizzolo/react-native-sectioned-multi-select/blob/9c5f71852aef7a7ac03e7761d5dd810cd2ccef5d/exampleapp/App.js#L322-L397][1]

```
container
modalWrapper 
backdrop 
listContainer
selectToggle
selectToggleText
item
selectedItem
subItem
itemText selectedItemText
selectedSubItemText selectedSubItem subItemText
searchBar
center
separator
subSeparator
chipsWrapper
chipContainer parentChipContainer parentChipText chipText
chipIcon
searchTextInput
scrollView
button
confirmText
cancelButton
itemIconStyle
```